# IndexedDB view all Databases and Object Stores

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, winjs, indexeddb

I'm using IndexedDB in a Windows 8 app and I'm very new to both. I've been able to successfully create, read, update, delete objects from object stores, and have created a couple databases and a few object stores. My question is how can I list all of my object stores and databases? I create a few bogus ones that are not needed and I would like to clean things up a bit, but I can't remember what they are named. Maybe this is anal retentive, but it seems like it should be possible to list all databases and stores. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is currently no way of enumerating the existing databases in the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/). Windows 8 apps use IE, which does not provide the non-standard `webkitGetDatabaseNames` method. You might be able to clear the databases using the [options dialog in IE10](http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/How-To-Manage-Browsing-History-And-Other-Private-Data-In-Ie10_9.htm).

Listing the stores inside a database is defined in the standard using the [objectStoreNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767347.aspx) method of an [IDBDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441231.aspx) instance.

Comment: Correct, and I think it would dangerous to have a getDatabaseNames method. This way hackers would have the ability to easily search for db's existing on the clients.

Comment: @KristofDegrave no that's not an issue because you can't do cross domain access to an indexedDB.

Comment: @user1133275 The same-origin policy doesn't necessarily protect you from an attacker being able to access it via XSS. If they inject a script into your page via something like SQL injection, their script would run locally in the page and be able to access it and then send that information somewhere else.

Answer (score 43):

At the time of writing this post [chrome 72], You can list all the databases using following command in console of the browser. Essentially  `indexedDB.databases()` is a `Promise`. You can use it to get list of all databases as an array. Run a loop on the array to get the names of databases.

```
indexedDB.databases().then(r => console.log(r))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `indexedDB.databases()` can also be used programmatically in Chrome

Comment: MDN reference: [`IDBFactory.databases`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/databases). Note limited browser support.

Answer (score 20):

EDIT 2018 This answer is no longer applicable:

`webkitGetDatabaseNames() is deprecated in chrome 60`

---

In Chrome webkit there was a function which would return all database names, this function is no longer available as of Chrome 60 ([webkitgetdatabasenames](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations#remove_indexeddbwebkitgetdatabasenames%22webkitgetdatabasenames%22)):

```js
indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames().onsuccess = function(sender,args) { 
  console.log(sender.target.result); 
};
```

And there is another function which list all object stores in a single database which work in all browsers:

```js
indexedDB.open(databaseName).onsuccess = function(sender, args) { 
  console.log(sender.target.result.objectStoreNames); 
};
```

Comment: [`webkitGetDatabaseNames()` is deprecated in chrome 60](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations#remove_indexeddbwebkitgetdatabasenames)

Answer (score 7):

Since all other topics reference back here as a duplicates. In Chrome you can view and delete all created databases in `Developer Tools > Application > Storage`.

To view IndexedDB internals: `chrome://indexeddb-internals/`