# IndexDB Database list

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

Is there a way for an application to get a list of databases assigned to it's own origin/domain?

I have an app that creates and uses multiple indexeddb databases.  It keeps track of each of them, but  I would like to be able to delete all the databases and recreate them on demand so a user can get to a 'clean slate', even if the list the app maintains is corrupted some how.

Comment: I don't think the situation has changed since [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234363/indexeddb-view-all-databases-and-object-stores).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I am webkit only so that solution was great.

Comment: Ther answer here worked for me [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234363/indexeddb-view-all-databases-and-object-stores][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234363/indexeddb-view-all-databases-and-object-stores

Answer (score 1):

Databases have two main characteristics: a name and version.

You can get away without knowing the latter, since if you open up a database without a version you automatically get a reference to the most recent version; however, with the exception of the non-standard (but insanely useful) `webkitGetDatabaseNames` in Chrome, you cannot enumerate database names for a given host.

A common pattern I see is to store database names in `localStorage`, which has similar "temporary data" cache purge behavior to IDB.