# Dumping indexedDB data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, dexie

Working on a Chrome Extension, which needs to integrate with IndexedDB. Trying to figure out how to use `Dexie.JS`. Found a bunch of samples. Those don't look too complicated. There is one specific example particularly interesting for exploring IndexedDB with Dexie at https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/blob/master/samples/open-existing-db/dump-databases.html

However, when I run the one above - the "dump utility," it does not see IndexedDB databases, telling me: `There are databases at the current origin.`

From the developer tools `Application` tab, under Storage, I see my `IndexedDB` database.

Is this some sort of a permissions issue? Can any indexedDB database be accessed by any tab/user?

What should I be looking at?

Thank you

Comment: Own pages of an extension have their own origin. Content scripts use a web page origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chrome/opera, there is a non-standard API webkitGetDatabaseNames() that Dexie.js uses to retrieve the list of database names on current origin. For other browsers, Dexie emulates this API by keeping an up-to-date database of database-names for each origin, so:

For chromium browsers, [Dexie.getDatabaseNames()](http://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.getDatabaseNames()) will list all databases at current origin, but for non-chromium browsers, only databases created with Dexie will be shown.

If you need to dump the contents of each database, have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/391), that basically gives:

```
interface TableDump {
    table: string
    rows: any[]
}

function export(db: Dexie): TableDump[] {
    return db.transaction('r', db.tables, ()=>{
        return Promise.all(
            db.tables.map(table => table.toArray()
                .then(rows => ({table: table.name, rows: rows})));
    });
}

function import(data: TableDump[], db: Dexie) {
    return db.transaction('rw', db.tables, () => {
        return Promise.all(data.map (t =>
            db.table(t.table).clear()
              .then(()=>db.table(t.table).bulkAdd(t.rows)));
    });
}
```

Combine the functions with JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() to fully serialize the data.

```
const db = new Dexie('mydb');
db.version(1).stores({friends: '++id,name,age'});

(async ()=>{
    // Export
    const allData = await export (db);
    const serialized = JSON.stringify(allData);

    // Import
    const jsonToImport = '[{"table": "friends", "rows": [{id:1,name:"foo",age:33}]}]';
    const dataToImport = JSON.parse(jsonToImport);
    await import(dataToImport, db);
})();
```

Comment: For anyone still interested in this, note that Chrome doesn't have this API any more either. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5725741740195840

Comment: Chrome has a different API now: [indexedDB.databases()](https://andreas-butler.github.io/idb-databases/EXPLAINER).

Answer (score 0):

A working example for dumping data to a JSON file using the current indexedDB API as described at:

- https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

The snippet below will dump recent messages from a gmail account with the [Offline Mode](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1306849) enabled in the gmail settings.

```js
var dbPromise = indexedDB.open("your_account@gmail.com_xdb", 109, function (db) {
  console.log(db);
});

dbPromise.onerror = (event) => {
  console.log("oh no!");
};
dbPromise.onsuccess = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  var transaction = db.transaction(["item_messages"]);
  var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("item_messages");
  var allItemsRequest = objectStore.getAll();

  allItemsRequest.onsuccess = function () {
    var all_items = allItemsRequest.result;
    console.log(all_items);

    // save items as JSON file
    var bb = new Blob([JSON.stringify(all_items)], { type: "text/plain" });
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "gmail_messages.json";
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);
    a.click();
  };
};
```

> Running the code above from DevTools > <kbd>Sources</kbd> > <kbd>Snippets</kbd> will also let you set breakpoints and debug and inspect the objects.

Make sure you set the right version of the database as the second parameter to `indexedDB.open(...)`. To peek at the value used by your browser the following code can be used:

```js
indexedDB.databases().then(
    function(r){
        console.log(r);
    }
);
```

Comment: how to recursevely dump all databases?

Comment: @Zibri: recursively implies some kind of nestedness which is not the case here — you are dealing with a flat structure; if you need all the databases then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55195418/191246 — `indexedDB.databases()` returns a promise; keep in mind that the API keeps changing so whatever sample code you find might only work in specific versions of chrome/webkit

Comment: I understand, but I wish to have all databases in a single json object

Comment: the API exposed by `indexedDB.databases()` allows you to build a single json object from all the databases that are exposed; just add them as keys into your own object eg `var allDbs = {}; allDbs[key] = data`