# Safari does NOT support indexedDB.databases()

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am using Safari 12.1 and working on IndexedDB with javascript.
I need to get all indexedDB database names but safari does not support indexedDB.databases() function [image]
whilst it is supported in chrome[image]

so how can I get all indexedDB databases in Safari?

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexedDB view all Databases and Object Stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234363/indexeddb-view-all-databases-and-object-stores)

Comment: About above comment, although it have a very old first answer, it continues to be right, the second answer there is edited of 2018 and it shows that currently only Chrome can list all DBs with `databases()`, there's no working method besides keeping track of all DB names in other browsers

Answer (score 1):

Looks better on safari v13.0.1 from august 29, 2019, 
so try the Safari Technology Preview version.

please check:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

[safari](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=Safari)

[https://bugs.webkit.org](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198278)

[https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/616#issuecomment-347501625)

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * Polyfill for indexedDB.databases()
 * Safari and some other older browsers that support indexedDB do NOT
 * Support enumerating existing databases. This is problematic when it
 * comes time to cleanup, otherwise we could litter their device with
 * unreferenceable database handles forcing a nuclear browser clear all history.
 */

(function () {
    if (window.indexedDB && typeof window.indexedDB.databases === 'undefined') {
        const LOCALSTORAGE_CACHE_KEY = 'indexedDBDatabases';

        // Store a key value map of databases
        const getFromStorage = () =>
            JSON.parse(window.localStorage[LOCALSTORAGE_CACHE_KEY] || '{}');

        // Write the database to local storage
        const writeToStorage = value =>
            (window.localStorage[LOCALSTORAGE_CACHE_KEY] = JSON.stringify(value));

        IDBFactory.prototype.databases = () =>
            Promise.resolve(
                Object.entries(getFromStorage()).reduce((acc, [name, version]) => {
                    acc.push({ name, version });
                    return acc;
                }, [])
            );

        // Intercept the existing open handler to write our DBs names
        // and versions to localStorage
        const open = IDBFactory.prototype.open;

        IDBFactory.prototype.open = function (...args) {
            const dbName = args[0];
            const version = args[1] || 1;
            const existing = getFromStorage();
            writeToStorage({ ...existing, [dbName]: version });
            return open.apply(this, args);
        };

        // Intercept the existing deleteDatabase handler remove our
        // dbNames from localStorage
        const deleteDatabase = IDBFactory.prototype.deleteDatabase;

        IDBFactory.prototype.deleteDatabase = function (...args) {
            const dbName = args[0];
            const existing = getFromStorage();
            delete existing[dbName];
            writeToStorage(existing);
            return deleteDatabase.apply(this, args);
        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @jamesmfriedman threw errors for me in Firefox, and when the IF statement was disabled would also throw errors in Chrome.

I stumbled across a PROXY method of intercepting method calls (from https://javascript.plainenglish.io/javascript-how-to-intercept-function-and-method-calls-b9fd6507ff02), and integrated it into the polyfill. This code works great in both Chrome and Firefox as of 2021-09-01.

```js
/**
 * Polyfill for indexedDB.databases()
 * Safari and some other older browsers that support indexedDB do NOT
 * Support enumerating existing databases. This is problematic when it
 * comes time to cleanup, otherwise we could litter their device with
 * unreferenceable database handles forcing a nuclear browser clear all history.
 */

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
(function () {
  // if (window.indexedDB && typeof window.indexedDB.databases === 'undefined') {
  const LOCALSTORAGE_CACHE_KEY = 'indexedDBDatabases';

  // Helper function from plainenglish.io to use a proxy to intercept.
  // Original at https://javascript.plainenglish.io/javascript-how-to-intercept-function-and-method-calls-b9fd6507ff02
  const interceptMethodCalls = (obj, fnName, fn) => new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (prop === fnName && typeof target[prop] === 'function') {
        return new Proxy(target[prop], {
          apply: (target2, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
            fn(prop, argumentsList);
            return Reflect.apply(target2, thisArg, argumentsList);
          },
        });
      }
      return Reflect.get(target, prop);
    },
  });

  // Store a key value map of databases
  const getFromStorage = () => JSON.parse(window.localStorage[LOCALSTORAGE_CACHE_KEY] || '{}');

  // Write the database to local storage
  const writeToStorage = (value) => {
    window.localStorage[LOCALSTORAGE_CACHE_KEY] = JSON.stringify(value);
  };

  IDBFactory.prototype.databases = () => Promise.resolve(
    Object.entries(getFromStorage()).reduce((acc, [name, version]) => {
      acc.push({ name, version });
      return acc;
    }, []),
  );

  // Intercept the existing open handler to write our DBs names
  // and versions to localStorage
  interceptMethodCalls(IDBFactory.prototype, 'open', (fnName, args) => {
    const dbName = args[0];
    const version = args[1] || 1;
    const existing = getFromStorage();
    writeToStorage({ ...existing, [dbName]: version });
  });

  // Intercept the existing deleteDatabase handler remove our
  // dbNames from localStorage
  interceptMethodCalls(IDBFactory.prototype, 'deleteDatabase', (fnName, args) => {
    const dbName = args[0];
    const existing = getFromStorage();
    delete existing[dbName];
    writeToStorage(existing);
  });

  // }
}());
```